# fatal: division by zero attempted when trying to find mean?

Tags: bash, awk, divide-by-zero

I'm trying to find the mean of several numbers in a file, which contains "< Overall >" on the line.

My code:

```
awk -v file=$file '{if ($1~"<Overall>") {rating+=$1; count++;}} {rating=rating/count; print file, rating;}}' $file | sed 's/<Overall>//'
```

I'm getting

```
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=[file] FNR=1) fatal: division by zero attempted
```

for every file. I can't see why count would be zero if the file does contain a line such as "< Overall >5"

EDIT:
Sample from the (very large) input file, as requested:

```
<Author>RW53
<Content>Location! Location?       view from room of nearby freeway 
<Date>Dec 26, 2008
<No. Reader>-1
<No. Helpful>-1
<Overall>3
<Value>4
<Rooms>3
<Location>2
<Cleanliness>4
<Check in / front desk>3
<Service>-1
<Business service>-1
```

Expected output:

```
[filename] X
```

Where X is the average of all the lines containing < Overall >

Comment: Can you provide your input file to question?

Comment: What is your input `$file`?

Comment: .. and clearly state your expected output

Comment: input $file is the location of the folder containing the input file

Comment: You are dividing by `count` on every line, even those before you've set `count` for the first time. You appear to just be missing the pattern `END` prior to that block. `awk '... END { rating=rating/count; ... }` (although you still need to ensure that at least one rating was found).

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error when I put the 'END {rating = rating ...}' in the line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an `Awk` as below,

```
awk -F'<Overall>' 'NF==2 {sum+=$2; count++}
                   END{printf "[%s] %s\n",FILENAME,(count?sum/count:0)}' file
```

For an input file containing two `<Overall>` clauses like this, it produces a result as follows the file-name being `input-file`

```
<Author>RW53
<Content>Location! Location?       view from room of nearby freeway
<Date>Dec 26, 2008
<No. Reader>-1
<No. Helpful>-1
<Overall>3
<Value>4
<Rooms>3
<Location>2
<Cleanliness>4
<Check in / front desk>3
<Service>-1
<Business service>-1
<Overall>2
```

Running it produces,

```
[input-file] 2.5
```

The part, `-F'<Overall>'` splits input-lines with de-limiter as `<Overall>`, basically only the lines having `<Overall>` and the number after it will be filtered, the number being `$2` which is summed up and stored in `sum` variable and count is tracked in `c`.

The `END` clause gets executed after all lines are printed which basically prints the filename using the `awk` special variable `FILENAME` which retains the name of the file processed and the average is calculated *iff* the count is not zero.

Comment: Can you explain how this works? I'm quite new to bash and awk. Thanks!

Comment: @daltojam: See if the explanation helped and solve your problem!

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You aren't waiting until you've completely read the file to compute the average rating. This is simpler if you use patterns rather than an `if` statement. You also need to remove `<Overall>` *before* you attempt to increment `rating`.

```
awk '$1 ~ /<Overall>/ {rating+=sub("<Overall>", "", $1); count++;}
     END {rating=rating/(count?count:1); print FILENAME, rating;}' "$file"
```

(Answer has been updated to fix a typo in the call to `sub` and to correctly avoid dividing by 0.)

Comment: I've got some unexpected output with this answer. The ratings in all the files are out of 5 but all of the output is greater than this. I think the logical OR is choosing 1 every time even when count!=0. However when I remove the "||1" every output is 1. Any ideas?

Comment: @daltojam the first argument to sub() should be "<Overall>", not "<Overall" (misses closing triangle). And yes, "count||1" seems to return always 1. BTW, anyway I prefer this answer than the other (after having corrected the mistakes...).

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F '>' '
   # separator of field if the >
   # for line that containt <Overall>
   /<Overall>/ {
       # evaluate the sum and increment counter
       Rate+=$2;Count++}
   # at end of the current file
   END{
      # print the average.
      printf( "[%s] %f\n", FILENAME, Rate / ( Count + ( ! Count  ) )
      }
   ' ${File}

# one liner
awk -F '>' '/<Overall>/{r+=$2;c++}END{printf("[%s] %f\n",FILENAME,r/(c+(!c))}' ${File}
```

Note:

- `( c + ( ! c  ) )` use a side effect of logical NOT (`!`). It value 1 if c = 0, 0 otherwise. So if c = 0 it add 1, if not it add 0 to itself insurring a division value of at least 1.
- assume the full file reflect the sample for content